# Get specific objects from xml document

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm trying to create an array, from a xml documents. The problem is i only want to get the objects where id is equal to `passedID`. which is a id from the previous viewcontroller. How can i implement this?

i've created this which gives me all phrase objects.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"lists" ofType: @"xml"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];

    rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"phrase"]) {
        translation = attributeDict[@"translation"];
        meaning = attributeDict[@"meaning"];
        pronounce = attributeDict[@"pronounce"];
        theId = attributeDict[@"id"];

        NSArray *cols = @[translation, meaning, pronounce, theId ];

        [rows addObject: cols];



    }

}
```

Comment: And, what's the problem? How are you using that code?

Comment: The problem is that i have a rows NSMutableArray. Which contain all the objects from the xml documents. How can i create a new array which only contain the objects where theId is equal to passedId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rows` array contains arrays of your data. This is rather inefficient and not very easily maintainable. You would be much better served using an array of dictionaries or custom objects. This will mean accessing the data by key / name which is more obvious and easier. It's also more accurate.

Currently, you can use a predicate to check if the desired id is `IN` the row array. But you could get collisions with other objects.

If you change to a dictionary or custom object (you really should) then you can use the key explicitly in the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theId == %@", id];
NSArray *requiredRows = [rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```